# A View and Scroll View inside a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am building a Calendar app. I have Navigation based app template. Navigation controller has segmented control having namely Daily and Weekly segments.

Upon clicking the segments i show the relevant View having status bar, navigation controller and bottom toolbar. This is working fine.

My daily view will have a top view and scrollView. Top view will have previous button, next button and date in label. When i add only scrollView inside my dailyView than it works fine, but upon adding top View it gives crash when i try to scroll the scrollView.

Please suggest is it possible? Else, what could be a better alternative? I even tried adding a second navigation bar (this time using the Interface Builder), button than i am not able to change the date in label. 
Please let me know if more clarity is required.

Comment: It's useful to post what programming language you are using, and giving the crash log could also help you in your problems.

Comment: I am using iPhone - objective C and SDK 4.

Comment: Post some code, description gives an idea of something wrong while adding the view but difficult to guess what it exactly is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have two questions:

> Please suggest is it possible? Else, what could be a better alternative?

So I'll go ahead and answer those questions:

**What you're trying to do is possible, so there's no need to look for an alternative.**

However, I guess the real question is: *"Why is it crashing?"* and I certainly would answer that, but without crash logs and(/or) code it's nearly impossible to give you a usable answer.

Comment: Also thanks Erick and Praveen for asking for code.
While collecting the code i found the issue. There were 2 issues:
1. I was actually adding items of TopView (namely previous button, next button and date in label) to dailyView and not the topView. 2. I was releasing autorelease objects also. So, it was crashing. Thanks again. Great job.

Summary: Always remember to add views to proper super view.

Thanks for helping me out to resolve this issue.